# Julia equivalent to the python consecutive_groups() function

Tags: optimization, julia

I am looking for a julia alternative with the same behavior as [more_itertools.consecutive_groups](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) in python.

I came up with a simple implementation but speed is an issue here and I'm not sure if the code is optimized enough.

```
function consecutive_groups(array)
    groups = eltype(array)[]
    j = 0
    for i=1:length(array)-1
        if array[i]+1 != array[i+1]
            push!(groups, array[j+1:i])
            j = i
        end
    end
    push!(groups, array[j+1:end])
    return groups
end
```

Comment: Start out by typing the array groups, I.e. `groups = eltype(array)[]`. It may make things faster if the element type is primitive

Comment: @FredrikBagge noted and edited, thank you.

Comment: `eltype(array)` is incorrect. You need to store a vector of elements of `eltype(array)` in your array. This is what laborg shows in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is already quite fast. If you know that the consecutive groups will be large you might want to just increase the index instead of  `pushing` every element:

```
function consecutive_groups_2(v)
  n = length(v)
  groups = Vector{Vector{eltype(v)}}()

  i = j = 1
  while i <= n && j <= n
    j = i
    while j < n  && v[j] + 1 == v[j + 1] 
      j += 1
    end
    push!(groups,v[i:j])
    i = j + 1
  end

  return groups
end
```

which is roughly 33% faster on large groups:

```
julia> x = collect(1:100000);

julia> @btime consecutive_groups(x)
  165.939 μs (4 allocations: 781.45 KiB)
1-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  …  99991, 99992, 99993, 99994, 99995, 99996, 99997, 99998, 99999, 100000]

julia> @btime consecutive_groups_2(x)
  114.830 μs (4 allocations: 781.45 KiB)
1-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  …  99991, 99992, 99993, 99994, 99995, 99996, 99997, 99998, 99999, 100000]
```

Comment: As a small comment it would be more generic to create `groups` as a local vairable on top of the function and instantiate it when you push a first group to it like this `groups = [v[i:j]]`. The reason is that you cannot be sure that `v[i:j]` produces a `Vector`, as custom `AbstractArray` might return something else when being indexed into (e.g. sparse vectors return sparse vectors).

Comment: Or `groups = Vector{typeof(v[1:0])}()`.